# Возвращение массива

Tags: javascript

Прочитал из учебника этот отрывок:

> **Shift** удаляет из массива первый элемент и возвращает его:

И у меня возник вопрос: что и куда возвращает **Shift?**

```js
let fruits = ["Яблоко", "Апельсин", "Груша"];

alert(fruits.shift()); 
alert(fruits);
```

Comment: Метод может вернуть значение, в данном случае возвращается значение первого элемента массива. Например, можно вернуть в переменную: `let shiftedFruit = fruits.shift()`.

Comment: Что возвращает? -- значение, наверно ;). Куда? -- туда, куда написано в коде, разве не так?

Comment: Как он может вернуть первый элемент массива, если он его удаляет.

Comment: [_Метод shift удаляет элемент по нулевому индексу, сдвигает значения по последовательным индексам вниз, а затем возвращает удалённое значение._](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift#Description)

Comment: Shift сохраняет значение только в переменной?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let fruits = ["Яблоко", "Апельсин", "Груша"];

let removedFruit = fruits.shift(); // в последующем вы можете использовать это значение
alert(removedFruit);
```

Comment: Это понятно, что Shift удаляет первый элемент массива, но я не могу понять, как он может что-то вернуть, если он удалил элемент.

Comment: @Человек, `shift` читает первое значение из массива ("Яблоко"), сохраняет это значение локально (в методе объявлена переменная) , после удаляет первый элемент из массива и возвращает считанное значение. Примерно так

Comment: Shift всегда нужно использовать в связке с  переменной?

Comment: @Человек, нет, shift возвращает в место его вызова, а уж там можно и в переменную положить, и прибавить что-то: `console.log(fruits.shift()+" aaa")`

Comment: Но обычно Shift используется в связке с переменной?

Comment: обычно я вообще Shift не использую, т. к. если массив не мой, то и портить его я не имею права...но это уже более глубокая тема, с которой не все согласны.

Comment: @Человек, рад помочь)

Answer (score 0):

Элемент удаляется **из массива**, а не совсем.
Вы можете удалить из своего телефона номер занакомой, но номер у нее то самой останется.
Элемент мог быть и в 2-х массивах.

Возвращает -- означает -- туда откуда вызван метод, в определенное место выражения.
Как `sin(x)+cos(x)`.

Comment: или вот, подходят к вам на улице, просят сигаретку. Вы ее из свое пачки удаляете, и попросившему возвращаете.

Comment: Хорошо, а где сохраняется удаленный элемент массива?

Comment: @Человек, это уже как решит тот, кто вызывал. Вот в `console.log(fruits.shift()+" aaa")` -- нигде не сохраняется, используется для сложения и всё.

Comment: Это **динамический граф**; элемент, массив и контекст -- вершины; нахождение в массиве или переменной -- ребра, которые мы создаем и рушим.

Comment: Но если его нужно сохранить, то сохраняют shift в переменной?

Comment: сохраняют не shift, а то, что он вернул

Comment: Удаленное значение обычно сохраняют в переменную, дабы потом его использовать. Я все правильно понял?

Comment: @Человек, ну да, обычно те кто любит shift сохраняют в переменную, дабы потом его использовать.